# How does the VBA PageSetup.LeftHeader formatting work?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a function that will setup the header / title for every worksheet, base on the worksheet's name. I used the [online resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb225426%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and macro recorder to write this. But can someone explain how the quotation marks and `&` symbol work? Does it always require to have `"&"` leading the format, and can all the styling go under one set of `""`?

```
Sub SetAllHeader()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsName As String

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        wsName = ws.name
        ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&""Calibri,Regular""&22&K000000" & wsName
    Next ws

End Sub
```

I experimented and try to manually clean up the code by doing

```
ws.PageSetup.LeftHeader = "&Calibri,Regular&22&K000000" & wsName
```

But this does something totally different. I would like to learn and write this by hand if possible.